# Bipolar theorem proof

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

Disclaimer; This is literally my first time working with the weak topology. I'm trying to prove the bipolar theorem; the question is 3.7.8  on page 156 here; [https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/funcana-ams.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/funcana-ams.pdf)

We want to show that if $X,Y$ are real vector spaces and $X$ has the weak topology that
$\overline{conv(A \cup \vec{0})}=(A^\circ)_{\circ}$ where;

$$A^\circ=\{y \in Y| |\langle y,x \rangle|\leq 1 \forall x \in A\}$$
$$B_\circ=\{x \in X| |\langle y,x \rangle|\leq 1 \forall y \in B\}$$

In showing $\overline{conv(A \cup 0)} \subset (A^\circ)_\circ$ I wrote;

Suppose $x \in \overline{conv(A \cup 0)}$. Then take a sequence:
$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \rightarrow x$ with $x_n=\sum_{i=0}^m c_{i_n}a_{i_n}$ for $a_{i_n} \in A$ and $\sum_i^m c_i=1$. The calculation that $x \in (A^\circ)_\circ$ is then fairly trivial. However; I'm not sure I'm allowed to do this. The sequence lemma holds in first countable spaces only, and I have no reason to think the weak topology is 1st countable here (or at least I had no luck showing it). However; for convex sets weakly closed and closed (in the norm topology) are the same right? But then the question dosn't make any sense; my proof goes through the exact same way as if I had just assumed the norm topoloy. I keep going in circles here and am very confused. If I can't use a sequence, can someone tell me how to start?

Ok after some more research I found that convex hull of a set is just the smallest convex set containing the set, so I only need to show $A \subset (A^\circ)_{\circ}$ and that $(A^\circ)_{\circ}$ is convex?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to show $A \subset (A^\circ)_\circ$ and to apply the convex hull.